# Unicode Emoticon block issues

Tags: java, unicode

I'm working on an IRC bot to moderate some chatrooms, and I'm having issues with the unicode emoticon block being converted into multiple other characters, rather than just staying as the single character. For instance,  converts into ≡ƒÿ? which is pretty much useless to me, as I'm trying to find and delete emoji from chat. Any ideas on how to prevent this?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!
-MoT

Comment: Do you know anything about Unicode encodings?

Comment: Not at all. this is all absolutely new to me.

Comment: It's likely that you're reading a [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) stream, and then assuming that each byte is a character, which is incorrect.  [See here for details about UTF-8.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)

Comment: You've put me on the right tack again! Thank you so much!